# How to implement Image Classification and feature extraction using Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, svm, feature-extraction

I'm currently performing a research that involves identification of food items using image classification techniques, I'm well versed in the theories and maths of SVM, yet I'm completely lost when it comes to implementing it using Matlab.

I would like some guiding steps to perform full image classification of food, I believe it will involve color, texture, shape and size features. I just wanted to know where should I start?

Thank you very much